# REST standard for checking if resource exists

Tags: web-services, rest, web

What is the REST way to check if resource exists or not? 
Let say you have some resource called Project.
By my understating one of this would be the way :

GET the resource

```
GET /rest/projects/123

GET /rest/projects/someCriteria

GET /rest/projects/listOfIds
```

simple but this way the entire object is retrieved if available and we just want to check if it is there.
Is there more elegant solution, maybe using HEAD?

Comment: Yes, use `HEAD` and check for `404`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The REST way is to use whatever the uniform interface allows in your specific architecture. For HTTP the best match is `HEAD`. If you need information beyond the simple existence of a resource, consider `OPTIONS`.